# linq query for common associations

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq issue that I am trying to solve, I have some users who can be part of multiple groups, now I am able to return which users belongs to a single group like so:

```
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    public List<Student> ReturnStudentByGroupName(string groupName)
    {
        List<Student> student = (from g in students
                              where
                                  (from t in g.StudentGroup where t.GroupName == groupName select t).Count() > 0
                              select g).ToList();
        return student;
    }
```

My problem now tho is I need to find the common users of multiple groups? For instance who are the common members of group A and group B. Im not looking for a list of users of these two groups it should only return users **if** they belong to both groups.

Does anyone know how to do this using two strings as inputs i.e string firstgroupName, string secondgroupName. Then return common students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you said you only want to return a list of users that belong to Both groups A and B, so naturally you just need to modify a where statement with two conditions instead of one.

```
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    public List<Student> GetIntersectingStudents(string groupOne, string groupTwo)
    {
        var student = from s in students
                      let grps = s.StudentGroup.ConvertAll(gn => gn.GroupName)
                      where grps.Contains(groupOne) && grps.Contains(groupTwo)
                      select s;
        return student.ToList();
    }
    public List<Student> GetIntersectingStudents(params string[] groups)
    {
        var student = from s in students
                      let grps = s.StudentGroup.ConvertAll(gn => gn.GroupName)
                      where !groups.Except(grps).Any()
                      select s;
        return student.ToList();
    }
```

Here are a couple methods for you, one of which takes two arguments in the method (What you asked for) and another that takes a list of groups (if you need to get from three, instead of two, etc)

**EDIT:**

I thought i would throw this extra method in there as well, just for fun. It compiles a list of all the groups and their members.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, List<Student>> GetStudentGroups()
    {
        var temp = from s in students
                   let grps = s.StudentGroup.ConvertAll(gn => gn.GroupName)
                   from grp in grps
                   group s by grp
                   into g
                   select g;
        return temp.ToDictionary(grping => grping.Key, studnt => studnt.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: @JungleBoogie: Yep, especially now that i just fixed it.

Comment: haha yeah I noticed the string aswell, well just going to give it a try and accept my apologies in advance.

Comment: argh you just changed your code lol which one is it this one or the one before?

Comment: Yup tested and works just the way I needed it to! Thanks Caesay

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<Student> StudentsOfGroup(Group g)
{
    return students.Where(s => s.StudentGroup.Contains(g));
}

IEnumerable<Student> CommonStudents(IEnumerable<Group> groups)
{
    return groups
        .Select(StudentsOfGroup)
        .Aggregate((acc, g) => acc.Intersect(g));
}
```

or depending on the number of groups the following could be faster:

```
IEnumberable<Student> CommonStudents(IEnumerable<Group> groups)
{
    var groupSet = new HashSet<Group>(groups);
    return students.Where(s => groupSet.IsSubsetOf(s.StudentGroup));
}
```

Comment: So how do you query that from a GET method? If you notice mine has "string groupName" in which I can use a GET method to query and return the result.

Comment: Well, you can easily rework the code to accept 'string[] groups' as input.

Comment: Since you have a Group type, you should use that. If Group only contains the name (that's all you included in your snippets) then you can easily transform a list of strings to a list of Group objects. But in that case you should also implement the Equals method on Group I guess. Or just rework the code to work with strings...

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumberable<Student> GroupIntersection(IEnumerable<Group> groups)
{
    return students
        .Where(s => groups.All(g => s.StudentGroup.Contains(g)));
}
```